# Error installing dropbox

Tags: software-installation

When installing:

https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -

~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Getting:

```
/home/ubuntu/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-160.4.4703/dropboxd: 15: exec: /home/ubuntu/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-160.4.4703/dropbox: Exec format error
```

I'm running this Linux instance through [multipass](https://multipass.run/install) with [GUI](https://multipass.run/docs/set-up-a-graphical-interface#heading--rdp-on-macos) on Apple M1, i.e., aarch64.

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details, no clues as to architecture, so are we to guess. Many of the unexplained details could be your problem, but we currently don't know as you've not provided the details.

Comment: What is your machine's architecture (`uname -m`)?

Comment: Look at the edit.